# What are good methods to prepare and vend cold brew?

Tags: cold-brew

I am considering in preparing a cold brew and vending at events such as music festivals/parties.  What are good methods for ideally brewing the coffee the night prior to the event and storing it, then serving it?  How should the cold brew be made?  My initial idea was to make several gallons via pour over and refrigerate and serve out of a 5 or 10 gallon dispenser with a spicket on site.

Answer (score 1):

For large batches of cold-brew I suggest to try out the [Toddy](http://www.toddycafe.com).

For more information (I suspect you have any knowledge about cold-brew) I suggest you to read [this article](https://prima-coffee.com/blog/what-everyone-ought-know-about-iced-coffee-cold-brew-31371).

Comment: In my opinion, it is always a better idea to copy the essence of the external links into the answer. The links may fade out in the following years and the answer  may become meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Go for Toddy if you want to do large batches. I suggest you experiment with the recipe a few times before you sell it to get the kind of cold brew you want and to get to know the coffee you are selling.

I like very strong cold brew, so my recipe would be 1:4 or 1:5 coffee to water (and I think this is roughly what Toddy suggests as well). Let it steep for about 6 to 12 hours, again depending on your taste. This gives you a concentrate that you can either dilute with water or I personally just pour a shot of it over a lot of ice and drink it like that. It gives a very sweet, full bodied cold brew. Most of the cold brew sold is way too diluted for my taste, I prefer the sirupy concentrate.

However you may not like it that way, so you could dilute the brew or experiment with the recipe. If the flavor is too intense try 1:6, then 1:8 and so on. I'd not go any lower than 1:10, although many people do. In the end it's a matter of taste and in your case how you want to sell it (diluted, on ice, in bottles etc.)

Also cold brew lasts a good week (arguably even 2 weeks) if you keep it refrigerated, so you can make several batches in advance with a toddy. If you start a week before selling you could make easily make around 15 liters (2 liters a night) or if you are ambitious even 30 liters (if you make another 2 liters during every day) of concentrate. If you sell it as shots (around 40ml) on ice, you can sell around 750 shots.

Comment: this is the route that I plan to go, do you have any suggestions on water to use?  I have spoken to a local shop manager and he has suggested reverse osmosis, however as a startup that might be a bit more overhead than I have intended.  I have also been suggested to look into mineral water.

Comment: Good mineral water or spring water should work. It really depends on how big you want to go. It's what I'd do if it's more casual. If it's your only income source and you plan to do it full time, then a proper water purifier would probably be the more efficient and cost effective choice. Just be careful that the water isn't too hard, calcium and magnesium are the two minerals that contribute most to that. You'll find info online on optimal water hardness and how to calculate it based on calcium and magnesium concentration.

Answer (score 0):

I sell cold brew in my shop.

Follow these elements, then find a way to adapt it into your situation. Grind slightly coarser than melitta brew, combine with cold water to a 1:12 ratio (g/mL), mix and pat until grinds sink, fill with water to the brim and seal (for air-free conditions). Let sit inside the fridge for 8-12 hours maximum. Employ a multi-stage filtering system. I use cheesecloth, aeropress, then melitta filter. Get that grinds out. Grinds exposure beyond 24 hours will make your cold brew sour. I observe the instagram posts of some successful cold-brew companies and it seems we've figured out the same way to make cold brew. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to sell anything here. Just came across [this article](http://dailycoffeenews.com/2016/11/02/new-manufacturer-coffeeworks-builds-cold-brewing-equipment-to-meet-booming-demand/) in Daily Coffee News.